# Restrict static IPs (Only DHCP) on Debian Squeeze

Tags: linux, debian, dhcp, restrictions, dnsmasq

How can i restrict access to the Internet for users with static IPs? Can i disable free dhcp leasing?

I'm running Debian Squeeze with dnsmasq as dhcp server. All users has their own ip, mapped to mac.

Thanks.

Comment: What is acting as a DHCP server? Are you asking how to disable DHCP?

Comment: dnsmasq is DHCP server. I'm asking how to disable free DHCP leasing. I want to give IPs only to allowed MACs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use dnsmasq as DHCP server
2. List all your known devices in `/etc/ethers`
3. List all your static IPs in /etc/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.intranet.conf. Ref: 
   [DNSmasq Installation & Configuration](http://sfxpt.wordpress.com/2013/11/30/dnsmasq-installation-configuration-5/#static)
4. Use the following (in /etc/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.intranet.conf) to ignore any unknown clients

   # Ignore any clients which are not specified in dhcp-host lines
   # or /etc/ethers.
   dhcp-ignore=tag:!known
5. Ref: http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq.conf.example